# How to send a simple string message in MVVM light with token

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

In my WPF Application I have many Subscribers to String message and many string message sends.
I know that I can differentiate between messages using tokes to select a particular recipient. Kindly direct to an example which does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you have two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` both registered for string type messages with something along the lines of

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, OnStringMessageReceived);
```

then you can send a message to only `ClassA` by stating the class type in the send template call such as

```
Messenger.Default.Send<string, ClassA>("Message to Only ClassA");
```

MVVM Light Author's blog has some relevant documentation you might want to read up on

http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx

Extract from above link(Function we are using for your requirement):

```
/// <summary>
/// Sends a message to registered recipients. The message will
/// reach only recipients that registered for this message type
/// using one of the Register methods, and that are
/// of the targetType.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TMessage">The type of message that will be sent.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TTarget">The type of recipients that will receive
/// the message. The message won't be sent to recipients of another type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="message">The message to send to registered recipients.</param>
void Send<TMessage, TTarget>(TMessage message);
```

Comment: On a side-note based on your previous question and since your starting MVVM recently, try to avoid plainly using string types in Messenger communication(Unless you absolutely need to ofc) as it does not give you any type safety and can become a nightmare to manage very soon very easily. Remember you can send any "Type" as a message. Try to categorize your communication into even simple enum types to give yourself some compile time type safety